# вернуть count без where, c where и результат select в одном запросе

Tags: sql, oracle

Для полнофункциональной (с поиском, сортировкой, пагинацией) реализации `ajax` для `JQuery Datatbles` требуется в JSON отправлять не только текущую порцию данных, но и `recordsTotal` (всего в таблице) и `recordsFiltered` (всего без учета "пагинации"). Реализовал тремя запросами и все работает, но очень медленно, где-то секунд 30 думает. Хочу собрать все данные в одном запросе. Сразу оговорюсь, опыта большого с ораклом не имею, вполне возможно, что мои решения сильно не оптимальны. Кроме того, проект сугубо внутренний, поэтому опасностью SQL инжекций можно пренебречь, что я и сделал. Сначала попробовал в лоб решить, ну да не учел сразу две вещи:

```
$add_like = empty($search) ? "" : "WHERE table_name LIKE '%{$search}%' ";
$query = "SELECT table_name, total, filtered 
            FROM 
            ( SELECT table_name, total, count(table_name) filtered  
              FROM 
              ( SELECT table_name, count(table_name) total  
                FROM all_lists 
                WHERE table_name NOT LIKE 'BIN$%' 
                    AND table_name NOT LIKE 'SYS_%' 
                    AND table_name Not LIKE '%_REP'
                    AND table_name Not LIKE '%_REP_QT'                        
              ){$add_like}
              ORDER BY table_name {$order}
            ) WHERE ROWNUM >= {$from} AND ROWNUM < {$to}";
```

Так вот, первое что не учел, это что что `count` захочет группировку, которая мне ну абсолютно не нужна, у меня единственное поле данных, остальное счетчики. Пробовал `count` заменить на `max(ROWNUM)`, все равно тоже самое. С другой стороны не хотелось бы три запроса, даже в одном (типа `union`). Так и так выборка делается, из нее бы только количество (два) забрать по-ходу дела.

Используется Oracle 12c база данных из PHP через oci8 и собственную надстройку.

### Есть ли какие-то способы решения?

Спасибо @Mike и @Sergey Moiseenko подсказали про over(). Вот мое решение, оно отработало чуть больше 5 секунд. Что вполне приемлемо.

```
$to = $from + $count;
$add_like = empty($search) ? "" : "WHERE table_name LIKE '%{$search}%' ";
$query = "SELECT table_name, total, filtered 
          FROM 
          ( SELECT ROWNUM as rn, table_name, total, count(1) over() AS filtered  
            FROM 
            ( SELECT table_name, count(1) over() AS total  
              FROM all_lists 
              WHERE table_name NOT LIKE 'BIN$%' 
                AND table_name NOT LIKE 'SYS_%' 
                AND table_name Not LIKE '%_REP'
                AND table_name Not LIKE '%_REP_QT'                        
            ){$add_like}
            ORDER BY table_name {$order}
          ) WHERE rn >= {$from} AND rn < {$to}";
```

P.S. Как правильно отметил Mike, тот вариант не мог работать. Просто между правкой и проверкой в коде, и постом сюда, был "потерян" правильный вариант. И сюда попал предпоследний c ROWNUM-ами во внешнем SELECTе. Я не стал еще больше увеличивать ответ, и просто исправил "правильный" код на работающий. ;)

Comment: Интересно, как это запрос у вас работать умудряется. Если по условию не включающему в себя rownum=1 oracle вернет пустой набор. надо переименовывать rownum и на следующем слое только накладывать условие. или использовать `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY` раз у вас 12 версия которая его поддерживает.

Comment: В вашем итоговом варианте total и filtered совпадают, потому что на уровне со вторым count() нет условия where.

Comment: WHERE будет в {$add_like} (см. выше, перед запросом), да и спасибо за разъяснение с count(1), поправил в итоговом варианте. здесь уже не стал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если сейчас 3 запроса работают 30 секунд, значит у вас в таблице уже много записей. Когда вы соберете это в один запрос сомневаюсь, что вы получите менее менее 15 секунд, что то же очень плохо. Предлагаю как минимум кешировать общее количество записей в таблице в отдельной таблице из 1 строки. Вести его автоматически на вставку/удаление из основной таблице, что бы не пересчитывать при каждой выборке.

Запрос же на получение нужной части выборки и при этом общего количества записей, подпадающих под условия будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
  SELECT table_name, filtered_count
    FROM (
       SELECT table_name,
              count(1) over() filtered_count,
              row_number() over(ORDER BY table_name {$order}) RN
         FROM all_lists 
        WHERE table_name NOT LIKE 'BIN$%' 
          AND table_name NOT LIKE 'SYS_%' 
          AND table_name Not LIKE '%_REP'
          AND table_name Not LIKE '%_REP_QT'
    ) X
   WHERE RN >= {$from} AND RN < {$to}
```

`count(1) over()` даст в каждой строке результата общее количество строк в выборке. Обратите внимание, `count(1)` обычно работает несколько быстрее, чем `count(имя-колонки)` потому как ему не надо проверять значение в скобках на NULL и его стоит использовать всегда, кроме случаев, когда надо получить количество именно NOT NULL значений колонки. `row_number() over(order by ...)`, в отличие от rownum, позволяет сразу получить нумерацию в нужном порядке записей без использования дополнительного уровня вложенности в запросе.

Что касается оптимизации по скорости, скорее всего надо полностью пересматривать подход, потому что условия `like '%...'` по индексам не могут работать в принципе и дадут полный перебор таблицы. А полный перебор надо исключить. Тут надо рассмотреть всю задачу в комплексе, продумать как будет осуществляться поиск по каждому из возможных атрибутов, попробовать, посмотреть планы выполнения (по explain plan)

P.S. Для 12 версии оракла, вместо использования row_number и внешнего слоя отбора записей по номерам можно использовать конструкцию:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM ... WHERE ...
 ORDER BY ...
 OFFSET {from} ROWS FETCH NEXT количество ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Спасибо, я в вопросе поместил свой ответ. Он отработал 5-6 секунд где-то. Что очень приемлемо.

Comment: @EugenOS Рекомендую посмотреть `explain plan` по запросу, если там full scan, то эти 5 секунд с ростом количества записей в таблице со временем могут привести к сильному проседанию скорости. У меня как то был один небольшой запросик, который отлично работал 2 года, но как только размер таблицы превысил объем кеша БД нагрузка на диски при его выполнении выросла в 5 раз и вся система стала дико тормозить.

Answer (score 0):

Ну во-первых для пагинации нужнен только номер страницы(следующей или текущей - не важно). А второе, ваш запрос чрезмерно не оправдан Вашей задачей.
Пример запроса для пагинации (вывод по 10 элементов) на MySQL:

**"SELECT * FROM pages ORDER BY publishedAt DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET {$page_num*10};"**

*Узнать общее кол-во найденных строк:*

**"SELECT FOUND_ROWS();"**

Пример на Oracle:

**"SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.*, rownum rnum FROM (pages) a where rownum <= $max_row) WHERE rnum >= $min_row";**

Comment: там приходят два параметра start и length, размер страницы меняется. кроме того приходит порядок сортировки, строка поиска (фильтрации)...основное что нужно это не просто пагинация, а пагинация с поиском. И требуется передать количество всего и количество фильтрованых всего. Т.е. мне эти значения нужно получить

Comment: но про offset и limit спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: start - это и есть page_num в моем примере. А число 10 замените на length.

Comment: это все хорошо. но я хочу получить еще счетчики. в этом запросе. это основной вопрос.

Comment: @EugenOS добавил в ответ

Comment: @КириллМатасов Вы обратили внимание на метку oracle?

Comment: Да, кстати, вспоминал почему я не юзал LIMIT или TOP...потому что они в мускуле, а у меня оракл. Он не знает LIMIT, да и FOUND_ROWS() это тоже про MySQL. Пока писал, кто-то уже тоже отметил...

Comment: Там, где вам нужно общее число строк, используйте count(*) over() вместо count.

Comment: @Кирилл Матасов, с пагинацией у меня проблем нет. Проблемы с count'ами. Вернее с тем есть ли способ забрать два каунта (или max(ROWNUM)) из вложенных запросов, до применения "ROWNUM  <> $from/$to". т.е. сейчас я получаю свои данные, а потом делаю еще два запроса с count(*) from. Но это по сути три раза одна и таже выборка делается. А запрос в вопросе, это одна из моих попыток получит все что надо за раз (неудачных попыток)        На счет count(*) over()  спасибо, полез в мануал...

Comment: @Sergey Moiseenko, На счет count(*) over()  спасибо, полез в мануал...

Comment: Во внутреннем подзапросе к сожалению `where rownum <= $max_row` использовать нельзя, при наличии там сортировки. потому что нужный порядок следования rownum будет только на следующем слое запроса, после применения order by. так что в любом случае все условия на номера строк придется делать после сортировки уже на внешнем слое